# how to bring two blocks closer

Tags: html, css

I was struggling wit this and found some way, I think I need to borrow power of css for this. please land me some skill if you know how. 
I have navbar like this,

```
<div class = "header">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>


    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
```

and second header

```
<div class="subheader" style="background:yellow;>
  <p>you</p>
</div>
```

now I want to bring these two blocks together so they look like one navbar divided by background color. how do I do this? I tried setting padding, margin to zero for both but won't work

Comment: Did u try going through django documentation? They have explained it pretty nicely there.

Comment: yeah I saw extending block is for extends "base.html" but I use "include navbar.html" I can't exxtend navbar because In template I'm only allowed to extend one

Comment: Ok your language is bit confusing in the question , just to be clear you have some content in 'navbar.html'  and you put it in 'base.html' and then  you want use 'base.html' in different pages to change contents of navbar. Am i right?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja sorry I'll edit the question, I think I found some way but it still doesn't work tho

Comment: Yeah please do that but what i commented was it correct?

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja no I found the different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you are using bootstrap, just set `margin-bottom: 0` for the `.navbar`. You might want to remove borders as well.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yyw99nky/